# Steam doesn't launch on 15.10

Tags: software-installation, steam

I am new to Ubuntu. I am running 15.10.
I'm trying to launch Steam but it doesn't do anything.

I saw that it still runs without showing anything on the screen.

What can I do?

[image]

Comment: can't read any thing in the screen shot. but try runing this in terminal. "sudo apt-get install -f"

Comment: Thnx for answering.
I did it and it was already updated. But nothing change..It still not launch steam.
the -f what install is??

Comment: @Milton Kalogiros that command will Attempt to correct a system with broken dependencies in place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
LD_PRELOAD='/usr/$LIB/libstdc++.so.6' DISPLAY=:0 steam
```

Comment: It solved

Thnx for help!!!